# Access file outside of server or root in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to view file which is out side of my project or drive. for that i added a key in web.config with a value of destination location. 
i.e.

```
<add key="fileuploadView" value="file:///D:\SubhrasData\xyz\I3ms\mis\doc\" />
```

now i get the path in following way

```
Dim path As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("fileuploads")
```

and assign path to view the file using hyperlink.

i.e. `hypSpCertificate.NavigateUrl = path & gObjDt.Rows(0)("VCH_DOC_PATH")`

but it first search in its folder first(in localhost). but i want that it should directly search the give file path.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value in key with name "fileuploadView" and getting it by "fileuploads"
Shouldn' this be like

```
Dim path As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("fileuploadView");
```